# Distributed topological sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

In my current project I have a large amount of data to be processed. The order of processing is important as there is a child/parent dependency in the data. At this point I'm building the dependency graph on one machine and distribute the work on multiple machines, but I'm reaching memory limit/processing limit on the "master" machine and I would like to distribute the entire process on multiple machines.

How may I build this dependency graph on multiple machines?

Comment: Can you say something qualitative about the length of the longest path in the dependency graph?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The paths in the graph are very short, most of them falling in the interval [2, 4] with few of them reaching 5 or 6. On the other hand the number of children can reach several thousands

Answer (score 1):

Since the paths are very short, the classical algorithm that finds all vertices of out-degree 0, adds them to the order so far, and deletes them will parallelize well (with, e.g., MapReduce).

1. Partition the job dependency graph among the machines involved. Each machine gets a disjoint subset of jobs and all dependencies involving those jobs.
2. (repeated in rounds) Each machine determines which of its jobs have no unscheduled dependencies. Those jobs are scheduled at a time equal to the current round number. For each job with one of the newly scheduled jobs as a dependency, the machine that owns the newly scheduled job reports this fact to the machine that owns the dependent job.

The total network traffic is on the order of the size of the graph, and the number of rounds is bounded by the length of the longest path, so this algorithm should be reasonably efficient for your use case.